# Class 'JsonValidator' not found

Tags: php, json

https://github.com/hasbridge/php-json-schema

Getting error  Class 'JsonValidator' not found.
I did install composer.json as in git folder.
I did put my json schema, json data files in src/Json and created a php file to validate as mentioned in git.
getting error class Class 'JsonValidator' not found.

Comment: Have you thought about adding an issue on their Github page if it doesn't work as expected or if their documentation is unclear? At least you need to show us your code, on how you're trying to use the library.

Comment: We need to see the code where you are trying to call the class. How was it installed (via composer, direct download, etc..)? Also, if you look at the class, it is not called 'JsonValidator'. It is called 'Validator' and is in the namespace 'Json', so should be called as 'Json\Validator'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In their example, they're creating a `JsonValidator` object.

This is different from the actual namespace of the class, which is `Json\Validator`.

Try dropping `use Json\Validator as JsonValidator` at the top of your file so that you're able to refer to the class the same way the docs do.

I'd expand their docs from:

```
$someJson = '{"foo":"bar"}';
$jsonObject = json_decode($someJson);

$validator = new JsonValidator('/path/to/yourschema.json');

$validator->validate($jsonObject);
```

To

```
<?php

namespace Your\Domain;

use Json\Validator as JsonValidator;

require_once('./vendor/autoload.php');

$someJson   = '{"foo": "bar"}';
$jsonObject = json_decode($someJson);
$validator  = new JsonValidator('/path/to/yourschema.json');

$validator->validate($jsonObject);
```

Alternatively, you could substitute `new JsonValidator('/path/to/yourschema.json')` for `new Json\Validator('/path/to/yourschema.json')`.

**Edit**: By the way - you might find the example schemas at [json-schema.org](http://json-schema.org/examples.html) helpful when using this library.

Here's the main one from that link:

```
{
    "title": "Example Schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
            "description": "Age in years",
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 0
        }
    },
    "required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
}
```

Save this file somewhere in your project and refer to *it* instead of `/path/to/yourschema.json`.

Comment: I am getting blank page, if I run the code. Is it the output for right data and schema..?

Comment: Hey @GokulnathSekar - what are you expecting to see, when you run the code? (This is only an example.)

`/path/to/yourschema.json` probably doesn't exist on your system, does it?

Further, it sounds like you might either:
1 - have error reporting off, if you're seeing a blank page.
2 - simply not seeing any output from the script, which is good - it seems to function not by affirming that the input is valid, but by throwing errors when it is invalid. https://github.com/hasbridge/php-json-schema/blob/master/src/Json/Validator.php#L53

I'd suggest taking a look at your error log!

Comment: thanks, and Yeah, I just want to proceed to next action when the json becomes valid, I just want an output that confirms the json validity so that I can feed it as confirmation so the program moves to further blocks of code